# SWT Control setRedraw behavior

Tags: java, swt

Experimenting on Windows with SWT `Control#setRedraw`, I've seen the `WM_SETREDRAW` is not always sent.

The OS message to stop/start redrawing is guarded by a variable `drawCount`.
That seems to mean if I do the following:

```
control.setRedraw(true);  // drawCount: -1
control.setRedraw(true);  // drawCount: -2
control.setRedraw(true);  // drawCount: -3
control.setRedraw(false); // drawCount: -2
```

then `WM_SETREDRAW: 0` is never sent.
I don't get it. Why is this?

The relevant piece of code:

```
public void setRedraw (boolean redraw) {
    checkWidget ();

    if (drawCount == 0) {
        int bits = OS.GetWindowLong (handle, OS.GWL_STYLE);
        if ((bits & OS.WS_VISIBLE) == 0) state |= HIDDEN;
    }
    if (redraw) {
        if (--drawCount == 0) {
            long topHandle = topHandle ();
            OS.SendMessage (topHandle, OS.WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);
            if (handle != topHandle) OS.SendMessage (handle, OS.WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);
            if ((state & HIDDEN) != 0) {
                state &= ~HIDDEN;
                OS.ShowWindow (topHandle, OS.SW_HIDE);
                if (handle != topHandle) OS.ShowWindow (handle, OS.SW_HIDE);
            } else {
                int flags = OS.RDW_ERASE | OS.RDW_FRAME | OS.RDW_INVALIDATE | OS.RDW_ALLCHILDREN;
                OS.RedrawWindow (topHandle, null, 0, flags);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (drawCount++ == 0) {
            long topHandle = topHandle ();
            OS.SendMessage (topHandle, OS.WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
            if (handle != topHandle) OS.SendMessage (handle, OS.WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @greg-449 thanks! The issue in my case is that I can't stop redrawing, and -that- causes flickering of a Nebula grid's cells.

Comment: The Javadoc says "Nested calls to this method are stacked" I think it means this drawCount code.

Comment: @greg-449 so basically nested setRedraws are a big no-no. I think it's difficult to avoid stacking this type of request as you never know what the code above or below you does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javadoc for `setRedraw` says

> Nested calls to this method are stacked

The drawCount code is doing this.

This will be to allow code to call `setRedraw(false)` and then call other code which turns redraw on/off without the nested setRedraw calls turning drawing on again prematurely.

Comment: Thanks again. Do you think I can somehow manage to "hack" into this process in a cross-platform manner?

Comment: I suppose you could use reflection to access the drawCount value in Control.

Comment: What I do now is keep calling setRedraw(false) 'n' times until the drawCount is 0. Keep track of that 'n', and call setRedraw(true) to match the old drawCount.
IDK honestly.

Comment: There should never be a reason to try and cheat setRedraw. Perhaps you should ask a new question explaining what the real problem is. If this is Nattable the author generally responds quickly to questions here.